# Selecting rows with a foreign key OR a join table relationship

Tags: join

I have tables like this

```
# Things
id
user_id

# ThingUser
id
thing_id
user_id
```

I want to select all Things where user_id=123 OR it is related to user 123 through ThingUser.

I think maybe I'm close with something like this:

```sql
select * from things
  left outer join thing_users on things.id=thing_users.thing_id and thing_users.user_id = 123
  where
    things.user_id = 123 OR
    thing_users.id IS NOT NULL
```

But on my very large dataset this hangs for several seconds and then I quit it.

Comment: "... this hangs for several seconds and then I quit it".  Why did you quit it???  Don't you want the result?

Comment: What's the point of `LEFT JOIN` if you put condition `thing_users.id IS NOT NULL`?  Isn't it the same as just `JOIN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concluded that the only / most appropriate way to achieve this is simply with a UNION. These two queries unioned together:

- where user_id=123
- it is related to user 123 through ThingUser

Answer (score 0):

1) Use Test environment if you have one

2) Alter your query to give you back a smaller sample size to see if that's what you're looking for:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * from things
  INNER JOIN thing_users
 ON things.id=thing_users.id
  WHERE things.user_id = 123
```

Comment: TOP is only valid in SQL Server, not a standard SQL clause